# Create an Instance of a Type, via Emit(Opcodes.Call, methodinfo)

Tags: c#, reflection, cil, il

I'm using Reflection, and ilGenerator, to create a .Exe, that calls a method from a DLL.

My problem is when it is an instance method, I have to put in stack the instance before calling the method. Therefore I have a method in C#, that creates and returns this instance. It is throwing `System.MethodAccessException`.

My question is, is this even possible? How does it work? By doing this in IL, `il.Emit(Opcodes.call, methodInfo)`, in the call that creates the .exe, when in runtime, how does it know what method to call? Does the method that I want to call, go to the .exe assembly? I'm very confused by this.

I go to the DLL, get the type, get the `MethodInfo` that I want to call.
I create a new Assembly->AssemblyBuilder->ModuleBuilder->TypeBuilder this new type that I am creating is extending the Type from the DLL:

```
 TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("TypeApp" + typeName, baseType.Attributes, DLLType);
```

I create the `MethodBuilder` to be the entry point of the new type:

```
MethodBuilder metb = tb.DefineMethod("Main", MethodAttributes.Public |
            MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(void), argsArray);
ab.SetEntryPoint(metb);
```

Then I generate IL for the `Main` method:

```
ILGenerator il = metb.GetILGenerator();

il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, callcreateInstanceMethodInfo);
```

The IL continues, but I don't fully understand this so far so...

Then I create the .exe

```
 tb.CreateType();
 ab.Save(typeName + methodName + ".exe");
```

Comment: Downvoters: please comment.

Comment: Can you show what you're doing that gets the `MethodAccessException`? I'm having a hard time following the description in the question.

Comment: yeah, downvote all you want, but at least say why, im gonna edit now

Comment: Create highlevel code for your problem, compile it and then view the generated IL with tools like [Ildasm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is throwing `System.MethodAccessException`.

Are you trying to call a method that is not normally visible to the type you are generating (calling a private or internal method, calling a protected method in a class you don't inherit from). I believe it is possible by disabling verification, but that increases the security requirements of the code which is a problem if you need to run in a partial trust environment.

> in the call that creates the .exe, when in runtime, how does it know what method to call?

The emitted IL contains a 4-byte metadata token, this is essentially a reference to a record in one of the metadata tables in the generated module (either the MethodDef or MemberRef table). If it's MethodDef token, then it's a direct reference to the methods definition, if it's a MemberRef token then it will provide enough information to identify the correct assembly/class/method to call.

The code you show generating the IL, indicates that you using the call opcode. If you are calling a virtual method, then you should use callvirt instead (although you can use call for non-abstract methods, it will result in calling the specific implementation ... even if it was overridden, this can be unexpected and I read somewhere that there were added security requirements for using call on a virtual method of another object).